# remove text from text string that follows 2nd -

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, filenames

I have many files that have the following format:

```
misty mountains - final chapter-84jdodljdjlm.mp3
misty mountains - first chanpt-4jd0843l8.mp3
misty mountains - (final chapter) - fj084j4.mp3
```

I want all the text before the first `-` and all the text before the second `-`.  How do I extract just this text from the file name?  OR is it better to erase the stuff after the second `-` and before the `.mp3`

Comment: Befire the first and before the second: `(([^-]*)-[^-]*)`

Comment: what do you want to do with simplified name, use it to rename the existing file? If this is your intent, your question should say so. Do  you then need help writing code to process a group of files and rename them? If yes, please say so in your question. Good luck.

Comment: Yes I am hoping to rename files.  I have found that if I ask for too much at one time, my question can be muddled, so I just asked for the part I really needed.  But yes you are correct I want to batch rename files in folder using osx

Comment: @muraenok You should always add the final result of what you are trying to achieve to make the question less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use Bash Parameter Expansion

You can use Bash's built-in parameter expansion to strip portions of a filename from a [shell glob](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html). For example

```
for file in *mp3; do
    echo "${file%-*}"
done
```

If you want to rename the files, rather than just capture or print the modified filenames, then instead of an echo you might change your loop to something like:

```
for file in *mp3; do
    mv "$file" "${file%-*}.mp3"
done
```

### Testing the Solution

#### The Test Code

You can test this out ahead of time to see what the results will look like. For example:

```
files=(
    'misty mountains - final chapter-84jdodljdjlm.mp3'
    'misty mountains - first chanpt-4jd0843l8.mp3'
    'misty mountains - (final chapter) - fj084j4.mp3'
)
for file in "${files[@]}"; do echo "${file%-*}"; done
```

#### Test Output

```
misty mountains - final chapter
misty mountains - first chanpt
misty mountains - (final chapter)
```

Comment: Thank you. Amazing tip.  I did not ask question correctly at first, thank you for helping me to see a better way to do things.  I will look up this trick.

Answer (score 1):

This awk one-liner may help you:

```
awk -F- '{print $1,$2}'
```

test with your text:

```
kent$  echo "misty mountains - final chapter-84jdodljdjlm.mp3
misty mountains - first chanpt-4jd0843l8.mp3
misty mountains - (final chapter) - fj084j4.mp3"|awk -F- '{print $1,$2}'
misty mountains   final chapter
misty mountains   first chanpt
misty mountains   (final chapter)
```

to list all the files, you can try `ls -1 *.mp3|awk ...`

The solution is not general one, but I guess it would be helpful for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(.*?)-|-(.*)$
```

Try this.Just grab the captures.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/zR2tR4/22